# Javascript updated table field transferred to bean as blank

Tags: javascript, datatables, javabeans, updating

Using JSF 1.2.

After Javascript function `copy()` correctly updates `h:inputText` field's value of a certain row of a session-scoped `h:dataTable` and returns true, user clicks on a `h:commandButton` and enters into a session-scoped bean method to read table from row 0 to the end. however the filled field (verified in Javascript side) appears as blank in the bean.

**EDIT : ** manually entered `h:inputText` fields transferred to the bean-method correctly !?

### JSP :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{SessionBean1.w_Model}" var="currentR" 
first="#{Assignments.w_first_row}" rows="#{Assignments.w_total_rows}" 
rendered="#{Assignments.w_1_time}">

<h:column id="columnF">
   <h:inputText id="columnFD"   value="#{currentR['XXXXX']}" 
   disabled="#{currentR['WHIDDEN'] != ''}"/>
</h:column>

</h:dataTable>

<h:commandButton id="w_save"   
action="#{Assignments.event_handler_save}" 
value="#{Assignments.w_SAVE_txt}" 
rendered="#{Assignments.w_1_time}" 
onclick="copy()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabled fields are not transferred with current values to backing beans.
before transferring (clicking on the related button) enable the fields not coming.

hope this helps to whom may concern,